# TypeScript declarations for AmCharts

Tags: typescript, amcharts

I am looking for TypeScript declaration files for AmCharts. If anyone has them, please share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to make definitions myself. This is what I ended up with:

(NOT WORKING ANYMORE): https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/amcharts

the effort has been taken over and now the most recent version is at:

WORKING LINK: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/amcharts

Comment: You might try adding it to [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

Comment: this link is dead

Comment: fixed t he  link

Comment: Hey Aleksey Bykov(@Aleksey Bykov), how can we use this file,can you share am example of using this amcharts type definition. I have tried to use it and I end up with a compilation error which says 'Cannot find name 'Amcharts''

Comment: you need to do `npm install @types/amcharts` and then you can use `import * as amcharts from 'armcharts'`

Comment: Hey @Aleksey Bykov, I got the following error:@types/amcharts/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, 0.0.44 worked fine for me, but not 3.21.0. Any working samples anywhere?